# React Redux - Take Data from payload and display in component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux but got as far as the payload of my search results.
 Currently I am displaying the results without using redux for testing purposes only using createListItems () function.

Here is the code of the component.

**UPDATED based on answer below**

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const apiSearchURL = `api}`
    get(apiSearchURL, { maxContentLength: 400 })
    .then((searchResults) => {
      this.props.dispatch(getSearchResults(searchResults))
    })
  }


  renderData = (props) => (
    <div>
      <p> {props.user.username} </p>
    </div>
  )

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="my-4">
        <div className="recomm">
          <div className="recomm_top">
            <span>Search</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search_advan_box">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <select
              name="religion"
              className="mb-2"
              value={this.state.formValues['religion']}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            >
            ...

            <input
              type="submit"
              className="my-4 pri_btn p-2"
              value="Search Profiles"
            />
          </form>
            <h1>NEW Results</h1>
            { this.props.data
              ? this.props.data.map(user =>
              <this.renderData key={user.id} user={user} />)
              : null
            }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchAdvanced)
```

Comment: We can't help you without showing your action creators and reducers. Can you update your Redux state successfully? If yes, then use `mapStateToProps` and get the data. By the way, do not mutate your local state directly like you are doing in your `handleChange` method. Do it like that: `let formValues = { ...this.state.formValues}`

Comment: @devserkan yes, the state is getting updated with the new data based on search parameters. Can you give me on example of mapStateToProps to get the data that way you are describing. Appreciate it. And thanks for the tip - I updated the mutation code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to connect your component to the redux state with mapStatetoProps.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        data: state.data
    };
}
```

Since it is async, you will need to use a ternary expression as well as .map() to actually render the data to the screen.

```
         { this.props.data
           ? this.props.data.map(item =>
           <this.renderData key={item.id} item={item} />)
           : null
         }
```

Finally a functional component

```
renderData = (props) => (
    <div>
      <p> {props.item.username} </p>
      <p> {props.item.firstname} </p>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer because it makes sense. I updated code based on your answer.  I am not getting any data rendered although I have no errors. I updated the question with an update to my new code. Could you pls take a look ?